# mouse automation not to interfere actual mouse

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation

I'm trying to make some code that accomplishes repeating clicking jobs while I'm doing other tasks (such as web surfing) on my PC.

I've tried Pyautogui, but the library interferes my actual mouse while the script running.

Is there any python lib I can use for this purpose?

or any advises?

for example,

```
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '\n'
```

Such as this code, will move my mouse cursor to the location. however, I don't want that consequence.

Comment: You don't have to switch libraries -- even if there *was* one that simulated moving the mouse (like selenium doing web element clicks) without *actually* moving it. What you can do is get the current mouse pointer coordinates before the call to moveTo, then do another moveTo that moves the mouse back to where you were prior to the interruption by your automation program. A bit hokey, but automation is best suited for dedicated systems.

Comment: @RonNorris thx, but I thought there could be a way that creates somehow "virtual" mouse to simulate mouse actions without interfering actual mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Run it inside of a virtual machine.